Validate if a string matches a format string
In Ruby, you can parse a string into a DateTime based on a given format string, for example:
3.2.4 :001 > DateTime.strptime(Time.now.to_s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
Sat, 17 Aug 2024 13:31:00 +0000
3.2.4 :002 > Time.now.to_s
"2024-08-17 13:31:52 -0400"

Notice how strptime works even if the current time is more detailed than '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', which doesn't have seconds or timezone in it.
What I'd like to have is a way to validate a string like '2024-08-15 08:00' actually conforms to a format.
I know that you can use a regex to validate something like this, but I'd prefer something that could check for a datetime format string without necessarily even parsing.
My preference here is because %Y-%m-%d %H:%M looks cleaner than /\A\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}\z/ (also, if it happens to validate that it's a real datetime rather than 9999-99-99 99:99 that's a bonus, though it would be helpful either way).

One slightly hacky way: append a unique suffix to both the format string and the input string: DateTime.strptime("2020-01-01 00:00" + "\0", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M\0") works but DateTime.strptime("2020-01-01 00:00:00" + "\0", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M\0") fails.

@Dogbert A bit too clever/weird for my preference. If the user sends "2024-08-15 08:00\0 cheese" it's considered valid.  Not that that would happen outside of a hacker, but I'd like something airtight and more idiomatically rubyish.

Why not have a strict regex to check the syntax followed by Time.strptime to check the date’s validity?

BTW, DateTime is intended for historical dates. For current dates, you should use Time, see When should you use DateTime and when should you use Time?

@Stefan interesting article.  We're only dealing with current dates, though I'm curious how you could actually go wrong using DateTime if all your datetimes are modern.  They provide an example of getting it wrong with a historical date, I would like to see an example with modern being wrong because of DateTime vs Time.

Note: we are using timezones, though that has nothing to do with validating whether a datetime string is valid to my understanding.  But it might speak to using DateTime instead of Time

@BenG note that it’s not some random article but the official Ruby docs stating ”Almost certainly you’ll want to use Time […]”. Just saying.

Searching through Ruby's strptime implementation, I found DateTime::_strptime (it is publicly documented but starts with _ for some reason) which returns a Hash that contains a :leftover string containing the trailing part of the string that was skipped.
If the string is consumed completely, the key does not exist in the returned hash. If the parsing fails, the function returns nil.
require "date"

def strptime?(format, input)
  if (hash = DateTime._strptime(format, input))
    !hash.key?(:leftover)
  else
    false
  end
end

p strptime?(Time.now.to_s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
p strptime?(Time.now.to_s[..14], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
p strptime?(Time.now.to_s[..15], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
p strptime?(Time.now.to_s[..16], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
p strptime?("", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

Output:
false
true
true
false
false


Wish they made something like this public.
What if I just validate the length (rather than regex) then parse the time to validate both format and validity?

@BenG some format specifiers are variable-width, like %e which is the day of the month without 0 padding for single digit numbers. You could also create a mapping of each % symbol into equivalent regex and match that.

I guess I'm lucky because my case is fixed length.  On the other hand, I imagine most people being fussy about a datetime input format will be requiring a fixed length one.  Fixed length is also lexicographically sortable.
If I were implementing for non-fixed length I'd probably write a function to dynamically generate a regex based on format string.

@engineersmnky did you mean a single ! at the start? That fails the last test case.

@engineersmnky no worries. In a previous edit (which is not shown in the history because I fixed it within 5 minutes) I had a similar attempt but then I found and added this 5th test case where the output was wrong.
